# what is the purpose of this form of type assertion

Tags: go

In the [wrap file](https://golang.org/src/errors/wrap.go) in the errors package, I saw this type assertion:

```
if x, ok := err.(interface{ Is(error) bool }); ok && x.Is(target) {
        return true
}
```

What does this form of type assertion, and how is it different than something like this

```
type IsError interface{
        Is(error) bool
}
if x, ok := err.(IsError); ok && x.Is(target) {
        return true
}
```

It looks almost like its trying to assert that `err` is an interface literal with a single method `Is(error) bool`, but I thought interface literals didn't exist

Comment: That type assertion checks if the dynamic type of `err` implements the `Is(error) bool` method. It is different from your other example in that it doesn't need to declare a named type upfront, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is checking if `err` implements the function `Is(error) bool`. It is equivalent to what you described with the named interface. It is not an interface literal, it is an anonymous interface.